# Importing WCF services in ASP.NET core with synchronous methods

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

When I import a WCF service in my ASP.NET Core project it will only generate the async methods and not the non-async methods. Is there any way to not only generate the async methods? I couldn't find any good answer searching on SO thus far.

Comment: Are you asking about how to generate client proxy with both sync and async methods ?

Comment: For WCF Service provider, it will only generate the async method. Is there any issue with async method?

Comment: @MilanRaval yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the method synchronously, you can call it as below..

```
proxy.GetCustomers(departmentId).Result;
```

And if you still want to generate synchronous methods, you can use manual way as explain [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786601/Ways-to-generate-proxy-for-WCF-Service)